# Error creating Docker Machine host with Virtualbox drivers

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-machine

I'm trying to create Docker Machine host with VirtualBox but when run: `docker-machine create -d virtualbox dckr-host-1` appears this traceback error:

```
MacBook-Pro-de-Alberto:~ albertosanmartinmartinez$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox dckr-host-1
Running pre-create checks...
Creating machine...
(dckr-host-1) Copying /Users/albertosanmartinmartinez/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/albertosanmartinmartinez/.docker/machine/machines/dckr-host-1/boot2docker.iso...
(dckr-host-1) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(dckr-host-1) Creating SSH key...
(dckr-host-1) Starting the VM...
(dckr-host-1) Check network to re-create if needed...
(dckr-host-1) Creating a new host-only adapter produced an error: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif create failed:
(dckr-host-1) 0%...
(dckr-host-1) Progress state: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
(dckr-host-1) VBoxManage: error: Failed to create the host-only adapter
(dckr-host-1) VBoxManage: error: VBoxNetAdpCtl: Error while adding new interface: failed to open /dev/vboxnetctl: No such file or directory
(dckr-host-1) VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005), component HostNetworkInterfaceWrap, interface IHostNetworkInterface
(dckr-host-1) VBoxManage: error: Context: "RTEXITCODE handleCreate(HandlerArg *)" at line 95 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp
(dckr-host-1) 
(dckr-host-1) This is a known VirtualBox bug. Let's try to recover anyway...
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug. You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12 that is is supposed to fix this issue
```

But the host are created, when run `docker-machine ls` appears:

```
NAME          ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL   SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
dckr-host-1   -        virtualbox   Stopped                 Unknown
```

I have uninstalled and reinstalled VirtualBox in the latest version 6.1 and restart the Docker and the laptop but the error persists.

Anybody could help me please ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Mac laptop, I would say that when trying to download and install the ISO image it crashed.

To solve this:

> System Preferences -> Security and Privacy -> General -> Allow
> "Oracle" applications what are blocked.

Comment: Also another cause of not being able to create the host-only adapter: `docker` on `Mac` tries to use a host IP that lies outside of the range VirtualBox expects -- see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70373434/132735