# Cannot start Docker daemon at MacBook

Tags: docker, macos, docker-machine

I ran the command, `brew services start docker-machine`.

It says, "Successfully started `docker-machine`". But, I got error when I ran `docker ps -a`. Please help.

```
brew services start docker-machine
==> Tapping homebrew/services
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-services'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1488, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (367/367), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (266/266), done.
remote: Total 1488 (delta 148), reused 267 (delta 93), pack-reused 1121
Receiving objects: 100% (1488/1488), 437.97 KiB | 3.04 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (624/624), done.
Tapped 1 command (38 files, 540.5KB).
==> Successfully started `docker-machine` (label: homebrew.mxcl.docker-machine)
% docker ps -a
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

`docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default` gives me the following errors:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default

Running pre-create checks...
(default) Image cache directory does not exist, creating it at /Users/perryluo/.docker/machine/cache...
(default) No default Boot2Docker ISO found locally, downloading the latest release...
(default) Latest release for github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker is v19.03.12
(default) Downloading /Users/perryluo/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso from https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/releases/download/v19.03.12/boot2docker.iso...
(default) 0%....10%....20%....30%....40%....50%....60%....70%....80%....90%....100%
Creating machine...
(default) Copying /Users/perryluo/.docker/machine/cache/boot2docker.iso to /Users/perryluo/.docker/machine/machines/default/boot2docker.iso...
(default) Creating VirtualBox VM...
(default) Creating SSH key...
(default) Starting the VM...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "vboxnet0"
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

$ sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Docker machine "default" already exists

$ docker-machine stop default
Stopping "default"...
Machine "default" is already stopped.

$ docker-machine start default
Starting "default"...
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "vboxnet2"
Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet2 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

$ docker-machine env default
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running
```

Comment: `Is the docker daemon running?`

Comment: @Michelle ok, then `service docker restart`

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko `docker` cannot run natively in OS X, since it needs a Linux Kernel, so it won't never start as a service within Mac. Also, Mac uses `launchd` to control the services so even if Docker would be a service in Mac, that command won't do anything but fail. In any case, if she's using Docker for Mac (the application mentioned at the end of my answer) she could use `osascript -e 'quit app "Docker"'` for graceful exit and `open -a Docker` for starting it again.

Comment: Why are you using Docker Machine and not Docker for Mac? - They are **not** the same https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/

Answer (score 15):

Same problem here. I have found that `docker-machine` is trying to move its `HostOnly` `network` to `192.168.99.1/24`. This is outside the range VirtualBox allows on MacOS.

See https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#network_hostonly :

> On Linux, Mac OS X and Solaris, Oracle VM VirtualBox will only allow IP addresses in the `192.168.56.0/21` range to be assigned to host-only adapters.

That range corresponds to `192.168.56.1` - `192.168.63.255`.

The solution that worked for me is:

```
docker-machine rm default
docker-machine create -d virtualbox --virtualbox-hostonly-cidr "192.168.63.1/24" default
```

Answer (score 1):

You're starting `docker-machine` as a service but not any Docker Socket.

Once you have installed `docker` and `docker-machine` with `brew`, you actually need to run Docker on a Linux kernel, `docker` binary is just the client and you cannot run Docker natively in OS X.

So first, you need to create a machine with VirtualBox where you're actually going to run Docker. For that you should do:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
```

In case that you receive an error like:

```
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"
```

That means that you don't have Virtual Box installed, so you need to `cask`-install it on your MacBook:

```
brew install virtualbox --cask
```

Once you have already installed VirtualBox, it's time to create a machine with the aforementioned command. You should have an output like the following:

```
docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default

[...]

Docker is up and running!
To see how to connect your Docker Client to the Docker Engine running on this virtual machine, run: docker-machine env default
```

But still if you run `docker ps` or similar it will complain that the Socket isn't running. The reason is that Docker CLI looks by default for the local daemon, so we have to explicitly tell the CLI that we want to use a different one.

For that, run the following command that will tell your CLI which machine do we actually want to use:

```
docker-machine env default
```

Next time you run `docker ps` or any other Docker command, it will work and run on the created `default` machine.

PD: Remember to stop the machine when you're not using it! For that you can just use the following command:

```
docker-machine stop default
```

---

Did everything before sounded like a lot of work and you just want to use Docker now without any further work?

Install it as an application and forget about `docker-machine`:

```
brew cask install docker
```

That's it.

Comment: I got errors when I run the command, docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Error creating machine: Error in driver during machine creation: Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied (extended info not available)
VBoxManage: error: Context: "EnableStaticIPConfig(Bstr(pszIp).raw(), Bstr(pszNetmask).raw())" at line 242 of file VBoxManageHostonly.cpp

Comment: From the error code `Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005)` I could guess that is a problem related with permissions. Did you install `docker-machine` and/or `virtualbox` with an admin account? What does it say if you try to create the machine with elevated privileges?

Comment: I do not understand of installing docker-machine and virtualbox with an admin account. I login to MacBook as my ID, open a shell terminal, use brew install command. It prompt password, I had to enter the password. I do not understand "create the machine with elevated privileges". How to "create elevated privileges"?

Comment: How to "create the machine with elevated privileges"?

Comment: I mean if you used `sudo` for any of the commands. With "create the machine with elevated privileges" I mean to do `sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`. Anyway if you don't know about how to handle privileges on macOS or Apple Silicon, maybe you should desinstall `docker-machine` and `virtualbox`, and just install Docker as an application with `brew cask install docker`, it will save you a lot of headaches and it will include all needed dependencies.

Comment: I did,
`
$ sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Docker machine "default" already exists
 docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
`

Comment: Did you set up the environment after creating the machine with `docker-machine env default`?

Comment: ```
$ sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Docker machine "default" already exists
$ docker-machine stop default
Machine "default" is already stopped.
$ docker-machine start default
(default) Check network to re-create if needed...
(default) Found a new host-only adapter: "vboxnet2"
Error setting up host only network on machine start: /usr/local/bin/VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet2 --ip 192.168.99.1 --netmask 255.255.255.0 failed:
VBoxManage: error: Code E_ACCESSDENIED (0x80070005) - Access denied
```

Comment: $ docker-machine env default
Error checking TLS connection: Host is not running

Comment: You're again mixing machines created with `sudo` with commands to manage machines without... Seriously, install Docker for Mac with the last section of my answer and forget about `docker-machine`, you need more understanding of basics about Unix systems before.

Comment: $ brew install docker --cask
==> Downloading https://desktop.docker.com/mac/main/amd64/69879/Docker.dmg
Already downloaded: /Users/michelle/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/78bcbaddfd15796b996ce894b4d55a745f341820632d6a84d37784d77032fda3--Docker.dmg
==> Installing Cask docker
==> Purging files for version 4.1.1,69879 of Cask docker
Error: It seems there is already an App at '/Applications/Docker.app'